# Prove: $x^4 + y^4 + z^4 - 4(x^3 + y^3 + z^3) + 5(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \leqslant 4 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, contest-math, muirhead-inequality

Prove that $$x^4 + y^4 + z^4 - 4(x^3 + y^3 + z^3) + 5(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \leqslant 4$$ for all $x, y, z \geqslant 0$ satisfying $x + y + z = 2$. When does equality occur?

---

Here is my aproach:

For each $x\in [0,2]$ we have: $$x^4-4x^3+5x^2-2x\leq 0$$

since $$(x-1)^2(x-2)x\leq 0$$

Equality holds for any permutation of $0,0,2$ or $0,1,1$.

---

Any idea how to solve this with Muirhead or Am-Gm or Cauchy?

Comment: What makes you think AM-GM or Cauchy can tackle the problem? I have doubts because (i) the equality condition is not unique (ii) none of equality conditions is symmetric for $x$, $y$, and $z$.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. What about with Muirhead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The homogenization gives
$$\frac{1}{4}(x+y+z)^4-\frac{5}{4}(x^2+y^2+z^2)(x+y+z)^2+2(x+y+z)(x^3+y^3+z^3)-x^4-y^4-z^4\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^3y+x^3z-2x^2y^2+x^2yz)\geq0,$$ which is true by AM-GM or by Muirhead because $(3,1,0)\succ(2,2,0).$

Comment: Do you like the problem

Comment: @greedoid I think it's an easy problem, but it's an inequality and I always like to prove inequalities.

Comment: Which inequalitev do you very like? @Michael Rozenberg

Comment: I love all the inequalities.Polynomials, symmetricals, cyclicals, radicals, exponentials, geometricals,...

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Did you see [Solving $\log_3\left(4-\sin 3x\right)\leq \cos \frac{12x}{5}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2931490/solving-log-3-left4-sin-3x-right-leq-cos-frac12x5)? Unfortunately it was considered as "off-topic". I've lost 343 of reputation just because I like to solve new user's question. :(